# How can I prevent 2nd order SQL attacks?

Tags: php, sql, xss, sql-injection, code-injection

I'm using PHP PDO for my queries, everywhere, but I read that in very *rare* cases there could still be "second order injections" where an unsafe variable is stored then executed when used in another statement.

Will prepared statements still protect against this? As long as I make sure I *always* use them? Or do I have to take more precautions? Am I still vulnerable to XSS attacks?

I also have a couple more questions, just out of curiosity, if you all don't mind:

1. Is it possible to have an SQL Injection with only alphanumeric characters, spaces, and one dash? Like `select * from something where name='$some_variable'`. All the examples I've seen seem to require other characters like semicolons, quotes, or double dashes.
2. I've read many SQL examples where the unsafe variable could be set to form another statement, eg

   ```
   $foo = "foo'); INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('hi";
   $bar = ("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('$foo')");
   ```

But I just tested and `mysql_query` doesn't even allow multiple statements. I know you can still have injections within 1 statement, but can I confirm that you won't have problems with multiple statements in PHP?

Comment: A second order attack would imply that you're roundtripping data database->query->database - you can still inject yourself, even though you're using only "locally sourced" data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to beat a dead (or is it a very alive?) horse, but...

Injection can only happen when data is read by the SQL engine as commands.  In a very simple case, if you allow unescaped `"` characters in your data, and your data is encapsulated by `"` characters in SQL, they you have enabled an SQL injection attack.

The key to preventing **any** SQL injection is to properly validate and escape incoming data EVERY time, at the time it goes into the SQL statement.  An easy way to do this is to just use prepared statements, which take care of it for you, allowing you to safely pass parameters to an SQL statement.

Each database library has it's own way of escaping or using prepared statements.  In MySQL and PHP, you have `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, which should be used **EVERY TIME PERIOD**, when you are using the `mysqli` library.

The PDO library has it's own way, but if I recall correctly, prepared statements were a big part of PDO -- use them 100% of the time, and you will be OK in that regard.

Comment: So as long as I *always* use sanitazation or prepared statements I will be okay against any SQL Injection or XSS?

Comment: @op: Xss and sql injection are two different issue. For xss, you can use htmlpurifier. It does a good job.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent agains XSS attacks, use HTML Purifier, and never strip_tags(), see links below for more info, PDO prepared statements should be fine for SQL Injection prevention:

[http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/nj5t0/what_everyone_should_know_about_strip_tags/](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/nj5t0/what_everyone_should_know_about_strip_tags/)

http://htmlpurifier.org/